# Amazon MapReduce Hive calling Simple Queue Service

Tags: mapreduce, hive, amazon-sqs

I am new to Amazon's MapReduce.  Can anyone tell me how to easily submit a message to Amazon's SQS (simple queue service) from a Hive job?  I want to put a pointer to my job's S3 results into SQS for simpler automated retrieval.

Comment: You could easily wrap the hive job and sqs call in a python script

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call SQS from HIVE itself, however, you can create a script (as Steve suggested) that will call SQS and Hive. You can call SQS before the Hive script start as well as after the Hive job has ended with a pointer to where the result is stored (or will be stored).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach:

1. create a new DynamoDB table; setup a lambda that would push an SQS on each new item using SQS streams
2. in Hive, insert a record into that table each time you want to push an SQS